# NOT bounded functions that satisfy a condition.

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for **not** bounded functions that satisfy a condition.

Let $dx$ be a Lebsegue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Define
\begin{align}
\mu(A):=\int_{A}\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}dx\quad A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})
\end{align}
Then there exists a **not** bounded function $g$ which satisfies the following condition? :
\begin{align}
{}^{\exists}M \geq 0, {}^{\forall} f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R};\mu)\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g|f^{2}d\mu\leq M\int_{\mathbb{R}}f^{2} d\mu 
\end{align}
If you know that, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded interval and $f_I(x)=(2\,\pi)^{1/4}e^{x^2/4}\chi_I(x)$, where $\chi_I$ is the characteristic function of $I$. Clearly $f_I\in L^2(\mathbb{R},\mu)$. If the inequality were true we would have
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g|\,f_I^2\,d\mu=\int_I|g|\,dx\le M\int_{\mathbb{R}}\,f_I^2\,d\mu=M\,|I|.
$$
Then, for all bounded imtervals $I$ we would have
$$
\frac{1}{|I|}\int_I|g|\,dx\le M,
$$
which implies that $|g|\le M$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understood.